# Remove duplicates nsmutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently removing this way:

```
[Refs setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:Refs] allObjects]];
```

However i wish to keep the order of the array before the removeduplicates

Any tips ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=[mutableArray count]-1; i>0; i--) {
  if ([mutableArray indexOfObject: [mutableArray objectAtIndex: i]]<i)
    [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex: i];
}
```